# Elegant timezone conversion in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I've loaded data into BigQuery with eastern timestamps that are stored as naive timestamps from the source data:

```
placed_eastern
-------------------
2018-07-23 00:00:03
```

BigQuery by default assumes naive timestamps should be stored as UTC:

```
2018-07-23 00:00:03 UTC
```

**Problem: I need to fix this timezone assumption.**

I currently have an ugly hack in place for fixing this error to ensure that the timestamps are correctly stored. This extracts the date and time parts of the timestamp out as strings, concatenates them, then recreates a timestamp.

```
select 
  placed_eastern,
  timestamp(
    concat(
      cast(extract(date from placed_eastern) as string), 
      ' ', 
      cast(extract(time from placed_eastern) as string)
    ),
    'US/Eastern'
  ) as actual_placed_utc
```

**Question: Is there an elegant documented way to handle this problem?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can convert to `DATETIME` to treat the timestamp as a logical date/time, then convert back to `TIMESTAMP` using `US/Eastern`:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP(DATETIME(placed_eastern), 'US/Eastern')) AS actual_placed_utc
FROM dataset.table
```